# Shiny help: Publishing and "Run App" will "grey out" but using shinyApp() works

Tags: r, deployment, shiny

I am working on my first Shiny App and it looks great when I run it locally, but fails if using the Rstudio "Run App" button or when publishing through shinyapp.io.

I've ensured that the directory is not local when publishing through shinyapp.io and that the csv file is located in the applications folder. I have checked the performance of the app using profvis and the app is using 352.9 MB memory and at 1060 ms.

Here is the ui document:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(readr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(ggrepel)
library(rsconnect)
library(devtools)


#master document. replaced with github data for sharing
df1 <- read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/KeithTStory/EnvironmentalAnalytics/master/Shiny/CABIN_explorer/20190522(2)_cabin_habitat_data_mda05_1987-present.csv",
                col_types = cols_only(Site = "c", Day = "i", Year = "i", Status = "c", Type = "c", Variable = "c", Unit = "c", Value  = "n"),
                locale = locale(encoding = "latin1")
                )

attach(df1) #odd that I am having to attach names. Seems to work with names attached though.

#Melt data to give each variable a column for selecting
df2 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  replace(., is.na(.), 0) %>%
  filter(Site != 0, Value > 0) %>%
  spread(key = Variable, value = Value) %>%
  group_by(Year) 

attach(df2)

#remove symbols that are causing issues. Tried to convert encoding but had no success.

colnames(df2) <- gsub(x = colnames(df2), pattern = "[+%-]", replacement = "")
colnames(df2) <- gsub(x = colnames(df2), pattern = " ", replacement = ".")  

df1$Variable <-gsub(x = df1$Variable, pattern = "[+%-]", replacement = "")
df1$Variable <-gsub(x = df1$Variable, pattern = " ", replacement = ".")

#This function is used to in the ui input choices for the y axis
FilterFunc <- function(condition, df) {
  subset.data <- df %>%
    filter(Type == condition)

  data_list <- unique(subset.data$Variable)
  return(as.character(data_list))
}

#useful variables for ui choices

types <- unique(as.factor(df1$Type))
df_sites <- unique(df2$Site)

### ui code_____________________________________________
ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("CABIN Data Explorer (Nelson River)"),

  sidebarPanel(

    selectInput(inputId = "site",
                label = "Select Sampling Site:",
                choices = df_sites,
                selectize = TRUE,
                multiple = TRUE,
                selected = "521"
                ),

    selectInput(inputId = "y",
                label = "Y-axis:",
                choices = list(
                  "Physical Data"      = FilterFunc(types[1], df1), #pulling from df1 since it is pre-spread and simpler to work with
                  "Sediment Chemistry" = FilterFunc(types[2], df1),
                  "Water Chemistry"    = FilterFunc(types[3], df1),   
                  "Channel"            = FilterFunc(types[4], df1), 
                  "Climate"            = FilterFunc(types[5], df1), 
                  "Substrate Data"     = FilterFunc(types[6], df1), 
                  "Hydrology"          = FilterFunc(types[7], df1), 
                  "Topography"         = FilterFunc(types[8], df1), 
                  "Landcover"          = FilterFunc(types[9], df1), 
                  "Bedrock Geology "   = FilterFunc(types[10], df1)
                ),
                selectize = TRUE,
                selected = "Ca"
    )
  ),

  mainPanel(
    plotOutput('histplot'),
    DT::dataTableOutput(outputId = "site_table")
  )
)
```

And the server document:

```
# 
server <- function(input, output) {

  DF <- reactive({

    df2 %>%
      select(Site, Day, Year, Unit, Value = input$y) %>%
      filter(Site %in% input$site) %>%
      na.omit()

  })

  output$histplot <- renderPlot({
    req(input$site)
    req(input$y)


    p <- ggplot(data = DF(), aes(y = Value, x = Year, label = Site, color = Site)) + 
      geom_point(stat = "identity",
                 size = 3) +
      geom_label_repel(fill = "white",
                       size = 6) +
      scale_x_continuous(limits = c(2005, 2018)) +
      # scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, max(Var))) +
      theme_bw() +
      theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
            panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
            legend.position = "none",
            panel.background = element_rect(fill = "floralwhite")

      ) +
      facet_wrap(~.Unit) +
      labs(ylab(input$y))

    print(p)

  }, height=300)

  output$site_table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    req(input$site)
    req(input$y)


    DT::datatable(data = DF(),
                  options = list(pageLength = 10),
                  rownames = FALSE)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

When I run shinyApp(ui, server) locally, everything looks great.

When I use the "Run App" button in RStudio, I get the following message:

```
Warning: Error in serverFuncSource: server.R returned an object of unexpected type: list
  [No stack trace available]
Error in serverFuncSource() : 
  server.R returned an object of unexpected type: list
```

When I publish the app using the publish button in RStudio, the web document starts to load, but then "greys out" and says "Disconnected from server" with the option to reload.

Inspecting the console output yields a reference to js errors that I have no idea how to interpret (maybe you can reproduce and guide me?).

Thank you for your time and any suggestions! (Information on how to interpret these errors is welcome).

Comment: I don't know if this is involved, but you should probably explicitly load packages, i.e., `shiny`, `dplyr`, `readr`, and `ggplot2`. (BTW: using `attach` is generally a bad idea for anything outside of interactive work on the console. Even then I don't like it, but at least it's less problematic.)

Comment: Thanks @r2evans. Added libraries. Until I attached the names, I had difficulty getting R to recognize those variables. I'll look into a fix once I get this problem fixed.

Comment: The fact that you're having difficult getting R to recognize those variables suggests something else is going on entirely. (And attaching two frames can be very confusing.) Typically `dplyr` doesn't require any attaching to operate as-is. In fact, all of your code (before `ui` and `server`) works for me without `attach`.